# Escape PHP variable in sed command from Ruby script

Tags: php, ruby, bash, sed, escaping

I have a Ruby script that generates a sed command to replace some PHP code. The command is later executed via SSH.

`command = "sed -i \"s*#{find_what}*#{replace_with}*\" #{file} "`

The replace_with string will contain multiple lines of PHP code so the following escaping needs to take place:

```
  command.gsub!(/\n/, '\\\n ') # Handle new-line escaping
  command.gsub!(/&/, '\\\&') # Handle RegEx variable escaping
  command.gsub!(/(\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/) { |s| s.gsub!(/\$/, '\\$') } # Handle bash variable escaping
```

The command after escaping looks like this:

`sed -i "s*require_once('file.php');*\n    require_once(\$www_dir . \$path . '/file.php');\n           *" /var/www/something.php`

When executing this command manually everything works as expected. However if I execute the command via `Kernel.system` all the PHP variables are stripped out in the replacement string. Something.php ends up looking like this:

`require_once( .  . '/file.php');`

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why shell out to sed? When you can do the search and replace fully in ruby?

Comment: The command is generated in Ruby and sometimes executed locally but sometimes executed via SSH on remote filesystems where Ruby couldn't manipulate the file.

Looks like I just forgot a backslash:

`command.gsub!(/(\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/) { |s| s.gsub!(/\$/, '\\\$') } # Handle bash variable escaping`

seems to work.

Comment: If `$www_dir` is your variable then instead of `\$www_dir` just do `$www_dir` since you are using `"` around your `sed` script.

Comment: @JaypalSingh Doesnt seem to work if I don't have the escape character in front of the '$'. The PHP vars are stripped out of replace_with string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: try having single quotes around the sed command that way no bash variable substitution will be run. I'd try the ruby stuff out like this until it looks just right.

```
puts `echo #{command}`
```

If you're using SSH anyway, I'd just cook something up like this to be able to run it locally via ssh, makes it super easy to have total control by keeping it all ruby.

```
require 'net/sftp'
Net::SFTP.start('host', 'username', :password => 'password') do |sftp|
  filedata = sftp.file.open("/path/to/remote", "r").read
  filedata.gsub!(/foo/, "bar")
    sftp.file.open("/path/to/remote", "w") do |f|
    f.puts filedata
  end
end
```

see http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/sftp/v2/api/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's definitely another approach worth investigating. I'm worried about disk IO/bandwith however. Let's say the 'file' is 1mb. Your approach would require transfering 2mb (1 there, 1 back) - correct? Whereas sending the sed one-liner is much less resource intensive. 

For a high volume of replacements and large filesizes - I think the sed way is more efficient. Thoughts?

Comment: You could rsync the stuff to local, then do the replace then rsync the stuff back, that would minimize the data. Remember that in the case of  ssh - connection is not only encrypted but also compressed so you will not be using the full plaintext 2mb transfer but rather maybe around 20 % depending on the repetitiveness of your data.

Comment: Ah very good point. Something to definitely think about. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thought a little more about what your question is and updated the answer a little. If you find it useful please upvote. tnx.